# Set subclass of object when parent class is constructed (dynamic sub-classes)

Tags: php, oop

EDIT: To clear up some confusion, I am not actually using `Male` and `Female`. A better example would be parent-class `Animal` and sub-classes `Cat` and `Dog`.
I'm kind of new to OOP, but I've grasped it pretty well so far. However, there's one thing I can quite find a way of doing.
Firstly, I create a create a new object based around the user. The user can be be (for this example) male or female, but I cannot check if they are without checking in the database. I then need to create a new user object with the sub-class of their sex.
For example, here is my current (messy) code:

```
$user = new Person();
$userType = $user->GetUserType($userid);
if ($userType == 'Male') {
    $user = new Male($userid);
} else {
    $user = new Female($userid);
}
```

If I want to make a new object, I must do this every time, which is something I don't want to have to do.
Here's a little more code to help put this into perspective:

```
class Person {
function GetUserType($userid) {
        $db = mysqlConnect();
        $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
        // Get the players information
        $stmt->prepare("SELECT user_type FROM user_information WHERE user_id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $userid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($userType);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
        $db->close();
        return $userType;
    }
}
class Male extends Person {
    // Male based things here
}
class Female extends Person {
    // Female based things here
}
```

So, in the `__construct` of the `Person` class, I'd like it to check for the users sex and set the appropriate sub-class.

Comment: why do you want to have subclasses for Male and Female here? Is there different or additional behavior? Please explain the difference between those two classes.

Comment: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html

Comment: @Gordon Without explaining about the project I just chose an example to show that I'm looking for (a parent class that sets its own sub-class). My actual project does not use Male and Female, rather 2 other sub-classes. I have updated to give the example `Animal`, `Cat` and `Dog`.

Comment: @JosephDuffy thanks but that doesnt clear it up for me. The interesting thing would be to know how the behaviors differs, so we can see the real problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, in the `__construct` of the Person class, I'd like it to check for the users sex and set the appropriate sub-class.

Like already said elsewhere, ctors do not return, so you cannot do that. And ctors should not query the database anyway, because [that would be doing work](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/). If you cannot/want not create the correct subtype immediately via [DataMapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) or [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html), you can use a [State Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state):

> Allow an object to alter its behavior when its internal state changes. The object will appear to change its class.

This is one of the [Behavioral Patterns](http://sourcemaking.com/behavioral_patterns) from the [Gang Of Four book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns). The keyword, obviously, is behavior here. The State pattern is not about varying Subtypes (Cat, Dog) as such, but rather about the difference in the behavior those have. Hence my comments to your question.

#### Example:

```
interface GenderBehavior
{
    public function someBehavior();
    // can add more methods here
}

class FemalePersonBehavior implements GenderBehavior
{
    public function someBehavior()
    {
        // female specific behavior
    }
}

class MalePersonBehavior implements GenderBehavior
{
    public function someBehavior()
    {
        // male specific behavior
    }
}

class UnknownGenderBehavior implements GenderBehavior
{
    public function someBehavior()
    {
        // either implement a neutral behavior or
        throw new LogicException('Unknown Gender set');
    }
}
```

To create those instances, you add a [Factory](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory)

```
class GenderBehaviorFactory
{
    public static function create($sex = null)
    {
        switch ($sex) {
           case 'male':
               return new MalePersonBehavior;
           case 'female':
               return new FemalePersonBehavior;
           default:
               return UnknownGenderBehavior;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you add the `GenderBehavior` interface to the `Person` class and tunnel all access to the interface methods to the Behavior instance:

```
class Person implements GenderBehavior
{
    private $behavior;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->behavior = GenderBehaviorFactory::create();
    }

    public function changeGender($sex)
    {
        $this->behavior = GenderBehaviorFactory::create($sex);
    }

    public function someBehavior()
    {
        $this->behavior->someBehavior();
    }
}
```

Now when you create a Person the first time, it will instantiate with an `UnknownGenderBehavior` and if you try to call `someBehavior`, it will raise an Exception. When you call `changeGender` with either male or female as argument, the appropriate `GenderBehavior` will be created and set to `Person`. And then you can call `someBehavior`.

Comment: I've been trying to look over this over the last few days since I didn't get it the first time. I'm still struggling to fully understand it, but it has certainly helped, so thank you. My main problem is constructing the object. I create the object based on the users id, then get the rest of the information from the database in the `__construct` function. Where should I put these behaviours?

Comment: I'm looking into Data Mappers, and I've found http://phpdatamapper.com/. From looking at its uses I can see why it will help (although a little complicated for me!). Since I don't know much about Data Mappers until I have a play with them, can you recommend/reject http://phpdatamapper.com/?

Comment: @JosephDuffy If you dont have lots of impedance mismatch you can easily roll your own [DataMapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html). Create one class that knows how to fetch Rows from the database. Inject it into the Mapper. In the Mapper, map the row columns to the Object.

Comment: Due to my lack of knowledge around OOP and Data Mappers, I'll not use one for now and just get the project working, then improve stuff like that. An an OOP note, how is it best to store a users information for further use? For example, on Stack Overflow you can get your summary at the top of the page. I'm assuming it only stores a user id and display name locally and then fetches the rest when required? This would mean that an Object is not stored in a users local session, and it created whenever needed?

Comment: @JosephDuffy it's likely persisted in some sort of Cache but you can also put it in a Session

Comment: Thanks for the help. Hopefully I'll learn about this sort of stuff at University :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot choose what to return from a constructor, but you can take your hierarchy as is (`Person` is of unknown gender, `Male` and `Female` are known) and use something like this pattern:

```
public class Person {
    public function ensureHasGender() {
        if ($this instanceof Male || $this instanceof Female) {
            return $this;
        }

        // now construct a Male or Female object from $this and return it
        $userType = $user->GetUserType($this->userid);
        return new $userType($this->userid);
    }
}
```

So you can now call `$user->ensureHasGender()` as many times as you like and it will only construct a gender-specific instance the first time.

However, I think this strategy is questionable. What do you stand to gain from having separate `Male` and `Female` classes? If their behavior were so much different then this could be justified, but that doesn't sound too likely. Perhaps handling the issue internally in the class with lazy loading and appropriate conditionals would be better.

Comment: I have edited the original post to reflect some of the questions you (and others) have had. A better example would be `Animal` with sub-classes `Cat` and `Dog`